# Using sortable how can I disallow items of a specific class moving to a specific list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to have 3 lists with an item from list A or list B should be able to move to list C but not from list B to list A or vice versa. Also an item from list C should not be able to move to list B if it originally came from list A and the same for list A if it came from list B. In my attempt to solve this all items in list A have one specific class and items from list B another class.

The code I have so far is:

```
    $(function () {
    $("ul").sortable({
        connectWith: "ul",
        beforeStop: function (ev, ui) {
            if ($(ui.item).hasClass('ui-state-default') && $(ui.placeholder).parent()[0] == $HERE) {
                $(this).sortable('cancel');
            }
        }
    });
```

Where I have "HERE" is where I have been trying to insert such a condition. For now I have only been trying to put the limitations on one list since if I can get that to work the second should be easy.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use draggable/droppable combination instead of sortable, as there is a lot of logic you are trying to utilized already implemented. So list A and B are going to have draggable elements and list C droppable.

The droppable has an 'accept' option, where you can set a css selector filter for elements, that can be dropped.

```
{ accept: ".only-these" }
```

Comment: Thanks I am new to jquery and the sortable seemed to be the best option at the start but will give this a try.